# How to Format my HTML table to STOP repeated ID or Client Name from Database?

Tags: php, sql, html, frontend

I have question about Formatting HTML table after it's pull out data from the database.
Meanwhile, After the table is load in the Table, there are repeated Client_Name. There is a relationship of tables from my databases of ONE to Many relationship from the parent table (Clients) to the child table (Cards, and Sites).

My Database Schema:

```
+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| **Clients**   | **Sites**      | **Cards**    |
+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| Client_ID(pk) | Sites_ID(pk)   | Card_#       |
+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| Name          | Location       | repair       |
+---------------+----------------+--------------+
|Address        | Client_ID(fk)  | sites_ID(fk) |
+---------------+----------------+--------------+
|               | name           |client_ID(fk) |
+---------------+----------------+--------------+
```

And here is mySQL Statement:

```
SELECT 
    cl.client_name, 
    jb.job_number,
    jb.repair,
    st.site_name
FROM
    cards jb
        INNER JOIN
    clients cl ON (cl.client_id = jb.client_id)
        LEFT JOIN
    sites st on (st.site_id = jb.site_id)
WHERE
    anD cl.client_id = jb.client_id
```

and my HTML code for showing data in table is

```
<table width='100%' cellpadding= '1' border='0'>

                        <thead>
                            <tr>

                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:Left;"><b>Date</b></td>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:Left;"><b>Job #</b></td>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:left;"><b>Site name</b></td>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:left;"><b>Description</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                                <?php while($userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($tresult)){
                                if($i%2==0)
                                    $classname = 'evenRow';
                                else if($i%2==1) 
                                   ?>                           

    <tr>
    <td>
    <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['client_name)']); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['job_number']);?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['site_name']);?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['repair']);?>
    </td>
                     </tr>                        
                                        <?php $i++;
                                }
                                    ?>         
                                        </tr>

                           </table>
```

This is how it Displays?

```
| **Client_Name*| **Job#** | **Site_name**|**repair** |
+---------------+--------- +--------------+
|client 1       | 899500   | Marcell      | rebooted 
+---------------+----------+--------------+
|Client 1       | 6623120  | Lovan        | cool-down
+---------------+----------+--------------+
|client 2       | 442120   | Brackes      | setup
+---------------+----------+--------------+
|client 2       | 546698   | client_ID(fk)| replaced
+---------------+----------------+--------+
```

I don't Want to see repeated Client_Name. What I need is: Client 1 listed is child 
Example:

```
    | **Client_Name*| **Job#** | **Site_name**|**repair** |
    +---------------+--------- +--------------+
    |client 1       | 899500   | Marcell      | rebooted 
    +---------------+----------+--------------+
    |               | 6623120  | Lovan        | cool-down
    +---------------+----------+--------------+
    |client 2       | 442120   | Brackes      | setup
    +---------------+----------+--------------+
    |               | 546698   | client_ID(fk)| replaced
    +---------------+----------------+--------+
```

Display on the HTML table. Is it Possible to display this format of table? What Do I have to Do?

**Please anyone HELP is Very Welcome!!!**

Here is my full code

```
<?php 
session_start();
include ('db.php');


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Company Monthly Reports</title>
</head>
<body id="main_body" >
    <div id="form_container">


                            <table width='100%' cellpadding= '1' border='0'>

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:Left;"><b>Client Name</b></td>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:Left;"><b>Date</b></td>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:Left;"><b>Job #</b></td>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:left;"><b>Site name</b></td>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:left;"><b>Description</b></td>
                            </tr>

                            <?php
                            $sqlSelect = "SELECT 
                                                    cl.client_name,
                                                    DATE(jb.date),
                                                    jb.job_number,
                                                    jb.repair,
                                                    st.site_name
                                            FROM
                                                        job_cards jb
                                            INNER JOIN
                                                        clients cl ON (cl.client_id = jb.client_id)
                                            LEFT JOIN
                                                        sites st on (st.site_id = jb.site_id)
                                            WHERE
                                                        jb.completed =  1 
                                            AND cl.client_id = jb.client_id
                                            AND jb.date >= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 30 DAY)
                                            ORDER BY cl.client_name ASC";
                                //echo $sqlSelect;
                                $tresult = mysql_query($sqlSelect);

                                $last = '';                 
                                while($userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($tresult)){
                                    if($i%2==0)
                                        $classname = 'evenRow';
                                    else if($i%2==1)


                                ?>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                        <tr class='<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>'>




                                    <td width=250>                                  
    <?php 
    if ($last == strtolower($userData['client_name)'])) {
    echo "&nbsp;";
}
else {
    $last == strtolower($userData['client_name)']);
    echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['client_name)']);
}

    //echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['client_name']); ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width=100>
    <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['DATE(jb.date)']); ?>
    </td>
    <td width=50>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['job_number']);?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['site_name']);?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['repair']);?>
    </td>

                                        <?php $i++;
                                }
                                    ?>         
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>    
                           </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @aldrin27 DISTINCT will not help for user

Comment: I Have used many time SELECT DISTINCT and Still nothing could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your php code at this place

```
<?php echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['client_name']); ?>
```

change it to something like this

```
<?php
if ($last == strtolower($userData['client_name'])) {
    echo "&nbsp;";
}
else {
    $last = strtolower($userData['client_name']);
    echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['client_name']);
}
?>
```

and you need a change just before the loop at

```
</thead>
                                <?php while($userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($tresult)){
```

change it to

```
</thead>
    <?php 
    $last = '';
    while($userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($tresult)){
```

that should do the work

Comment: I have try to do what you said. Thanks for help. BUT STILL the problem persist. The Client NAME Doesn't DISPLAY ANY MORE. what could be the issue?

Comment: Please check the PHP Script Update: $tresult = mysql_query($sqlSelect);
                               
                                $last = '';                 
                                while($userData = mysql_fetch_array($tresult)){
         if($i%2==0)
          $classname = 'evenRow';
         else if($i%2==1)
        . BUT Still I don't get it right!

Comment: You also replaced your line <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['client_name)']); ?> with my code?

Comment: Yes, I did. And there is all the data but the Client Name Disappear from the table . Please have a look: [Link](http://kopanang.co.za/monthreport.php)

Comment: And When I put my Code back: `echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['client_name)']);` It's working as with still repeated Client name.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ ... send my the url that is shown you after you submitted the code

Comment: I have Paste as you have asked. and on my Question up to the top, I have add my FULL Code at the bottom. Hope that may help

Comment: You have a typo in line 73, there must be only ONE (!) = to assign! (it is right after the else)

Comment: I Did and Still not Displaying the ClientName. Please check the code for yourself. [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/Pp1kiQpx)

Comment: time to debug, what is in $last and what is in $userData['client_name)'] in each loop ... between line 66 and 67 in your pastebin code, place a echo $last; and echo $userData['client_name)']; and analyse the resulst, maybe there we will find something.

Comment: OK! OK ok!!! After Revising your Coding that you sent me. I dig out that there was some simple error in your coding. And What I did is just to remove Parenthesizes that you added just after the ('). Here is: `if ($last == strtolower($userData['client_name'])) {
    echo "&nbsp;";
}
else {
    $last = strtolower($userData['client_name']);
    echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['client_name']);
}`. And Now it's Totally working.

Comment: I Have One Question That you may help me with! How would I send Email of Each Client name (All Details) To Random Emails: email@guess1.com, email2@guess2.com, ...?

Comment: Thank you Very much For Answering my First Question. I really appreciate You for all your times and help.